# Not all XML file creating while validating it with xsd

Tags: c#, xsd-validation

I have created a Code to create seperate xml file for each record and each XML first Validated with  a XSD file and than its file created if validated than in Filename "validated" append and if not than "Not-validated" Append.

my code is this---

=====================================================================================================

```
class myprogram
{
    public void GetAllXmlFiles(int CompanyId, int BranchId, int BookingId)
    {
        CompanyDataContext dc = new CompanyDataContext();
        var result = (from obj in dc.usp_Getjobdetail(CompanyId, BranchId, BookingId)//Procedure to get all record 
                      select obj).ToList();
        if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in result)
            {

                bool bIsValidated = true;
                XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "JobXML\\JobTemplate.xml");

                //Code for setting XML node values and adding new XElement 
                //to create full xml file.

                string sPayload = string.Empty;

                XmlSchemaSet xschemas = new XmlSchemaSet();

                xschemas.Add("", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\JOB-XML\\JOB.003.xsd");
                string sErrorMessage = "";

                xdoc.Validate(xschemas, (o, e) =>
                {
                    sErrorMessage = e.Message;
                    bIsValidated = false;
                });
            // added code to pause current process for a sec
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            //
                sPayload = xdoc.ToString();

                string filename = @"C:\CAPS-XML\" + JobUpdate.JobNo + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-     mm-ss") + "-" + (bIsValidated == true ? "Validated" : "Not_Validated") + sErrorMessage + ".xml";

                if (!Directory.Exists(@"C:/CAPS-XML"))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:/CAPS-XML");
                    FileStream fStream = File.Create(filename);
                    fStream.Close();
                    File.WriteAllText(filename, xdoc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
                }
                else
                {

                    FileStream fStream = File.Create(filename);
                    fStream.Close();
                    File.WriteAllText(filename, xdoc.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

=====================================================================================================

currently all files created from this code is validated 
but when I am testing i am getting 21 records so there must be 21 xml file in folder but it creates only 4  but when use break point at  it creates all 21 xml file so I 
added code to sleep current thread for a sec after the code where I validate my xml with xsd

So please can any body tell me why this happening?
And if there may be any other better solution for this problem please let me know.

Note: sorry, but I can not provide the code for creating xml.

Comment: actually this method is created in a window service  but when i was testing , while validating XML debugger paused for a while while validating so i just put this code System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); just to get result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating filenames with this line:

```
string filename = @"C:\CAPS-XML\" 
                + JobUpdate.JobNo 
                + "-" 
                + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-     mm-ss") 
                + "-" 
                + (bIsValidated == true ? "Validated" : "Not_Validated") 
                + sErrorMessage 
                + ".xml";
```

and as `JobUpdate.JobNo` is not in the code you show I have to assume it is a stable value. As your code works if you break on it or add a waittime of 1000 ms resolve the issue verifies this because waiting for 1 second makes this `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-     mm-ss")` change, therfore making the files unique again.

I suggest you add a counter to your filenames to make them unique. Using milliseconds to the timestamp might not be enough if your code would be able to create and validate the xml within 20ms. That might work on a developer box but once you run the code on production grade hardware you might run in the same problem.

```
if (result != null && result.Count > 0)
{
        int fileCounter = 0;
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
             // all other code here

            string filename = String.Format(@"C:\CAPS-XML\{0}-{1}-{2}{3}-{4}.xml" 
                , JobUpdate.JobNo 
                , DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH-     mm-ss") 
                , (bIsValidated == true ? "Validated" : "Not_Validated") 
                , sErrorMessage
                , fileCounter);  // this makes the file unique

          fileCounter++; // add one 

          // create file code etc
```